# Cannot configure CommonsMultipartResolver with Spring Boot 1.2.8

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, servlet-3.0, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to use `CommonsMultipartResolver` in my Spring Boot application. I cannot use the `StandardServletMultipartResolver`, as I want to handle exceptions (e.g. exceeding file size).

I have set up a dependency to `commons-fileupload`. My spring configuration is:

```
    @Autowired
    private MultipartProperties multipartProperties = new MultipartProperties();

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        return this.multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        LOG.debug("initializing MultipartResolver");
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean multipartFilterRegistrationBean() {
        final MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
        final FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(multipartFilter);
        multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter.DEFAULT_ORDER-1);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```

When I set up the `MultipartFilter` to be executed prior to the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` I get an `IOException`:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Missing content for multipart request
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:400)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2139)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractMultipartParameters(Request.java:385)
... 35 common frames omitted
```

Otherwise, I get an exception that the part parameter is not present in the request.

I believe I need to disable the servlet 3.0 handling of multipart requests, but I cannot figure out how to do it in spring boot.

Comment: Judging by the stack trace, it looks like you're using Jetty which you haven't mentioned anywhere. To avoid any other discrepancies, can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest` throwing an exception on `getParameter` which was called by `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, because the stream was already processed in `MultipartFilter`:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, >HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
>       throws ServletException, IOException {
>
>   String paramValue = request.getParameter(this.methodParam);
>   if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && >StringUtils.hasLength(paramValue)) {
>       String method = paramValue.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
>       HttpServletRequest wrapper = new >HttpMethodRequestWrapper(request, method);
>       filterChain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
>   }
>   else {
>       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
>   }
> }
> ```

My solution to this was to disable `MultipartAutoConfiguration`, not define a `MultipartConfigElement` bean in order to disable servlet 3.0 multipart parsing and not use the `MultipartFiler`.

Now the configuration looks like the following:

```
@Autowired
private MultipartProperties multipartProperties = new MultipartProperties();

@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    LOG.debug("initializing MultipartResolver");
    MultipartConfigElement config = multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setResolveLazily(true);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(config.getMaxRequestSize());
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(config.getMaxFileSize());
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Now it is even possible to use @ExceptionHandler advice to return the correct HTTP code when a file exceeds the maximum size allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Spring boot auto configures a MultipartConfigElement, see https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ Just remove commons-fileupload from your classpath

Be aware, that HiddenHttpMethodFilter needs to be executed after multipart processing, as stated in spring docs:

> NOTE: This filter needs to run after multipart processing in case of a multipart POST request, due to its inherent need for checking a POST body parameter. So typically, put a Spring MultipartFilter before this HiddenHttpMethodFilter in your web.xml filter chain.

Comment: I have disabled the autoconfiguration and explicitly stated that I dont want to use `StandardServletMultipartResolver`.